# Hibernate+Spring MVC. Получение и сохранение объектов из БД с внешним ключом

Tags: json, spring, hibernate, persistance, foreign-key

Всем привет!
Изучаю Java в целом, Spring и Hibernate всего 2 месяца, поэтому просьба строго не судить.
Пишу свой проект - RESTfull API приложение на Spring MVC с использованием Hibernate в качестве ORM.
Немного не понятно, как лучше всего проектировать API с учетом Hibernate.
В чем заключается проблема:
Допустим есть в БД таблица - "Книга" (Book):

```
public class Book {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int bookId;
private String name;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "Book")
private List<Chapter> chapters;
}
```

и таблица - "Глава" (Chapter):

```
public class Chapter {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@ManyToOne
private int chapterId;
private String name;
@JoinColumn(name = "bookId")
private Book book;
}
```

В таблицу с книгами добавлена запись:

```
{
"id" : "1"
"name" : "Alice in wonderland"
}
```

В таблицу с главами также добавлена запись:

```
{
"id": "1",
"name" : "Down the Rabbit Hole"
}
```

**Вопрос #1:**
При написании контролера я бы хотел, чтобы метод  **GET chapter/1** мне возвращал JSON вида:

```
{
"chapterId" : 1,
"name" : "Down the Rabbit Hole",
"bookId" : "1"
}
```

но сейчас, для получения записи из БД я использую метод get():

```
chapter = (Chapter) session.get( Chapter.class, chapterId );
```

который возвращает объект вида:

```
{
"chapterId" : 1,
"name": "Down the Rabbit Hole",
"Book" : {
    "bookId" : "1",
     "name": "Alice in wonderland"
    }
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при получении объекта Chapter вовращался объект со свойствами главы + идентификатор книги (а не целиком объект Book)?

**Вопрос #2:**
Аналогичный вопрос, но по методу **POST chapter/new** для сохранения новой главы.
Я бы хотел упростить REST API своего приложения - если кто то захочет сохранить в БД новую главу книги, ему нужно будет при вызове метода POST передать всего 2 параметра:
1. Наименование главы.
2. Ссылку на идентификатор книги.
Соответственно, при вызове метода **POST /chapter/new** я хочу чтобы мне передавали объект вида:

```
{
"name" : "The Pool of Tears",
"bookId" : "1"
}
```

Но так как @Entity Chapter имеет ссылку на Book, необходимо просить пользователя передавать не просто идентификатор, а весь объект целиком:

```
{
"name" : "The Pool of Tears",
"Book" : {
    "bookId" : "1",
    "name" : "Alice in wonderland"
    } 
}
```

Как поступить в этой ситуации, чтобы не просить с клиентской части передавать объект Book целиком, при этом, чтобы можно было сохранять средствами Hibernate объект Chapter в БД?

Для себя решил, что можно использовать промежуточные объекты - модели, для того, чтобы их заполнять в нужном формате на основе Entity из БД и потом возращать их на клиент (в случае с **GET**).
И наоброт для **POST** - при получении с клиентской части объекта получать некую модель, которая затем будет преобразовываться в формат Entity для сохранения в БД.

Но такой способ решения кажется костыльным. 
Просьба продсказать best practices для решения подобных задач.
Заранее спасибо всем откликнувшимся!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По Вашему первому и второму вопросу у класса `Chapter` нужно добавить одно поле, например `bookId`. Класс должен выглядеть так:

```
public class Chapter {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue    
    private int chapterId;
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "bookId")
    private Book book;

    @Column(name = "bookId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private int bookId;

}
```

Обратите внимание на то, что у поля `book` и `bookId` название колонки в БД одно и тоже, но поле `bookId` используется только на чтение из БД, при этом **не записывается** и **не обновляется** в БД средствами хибернейта.

По второму вопросу, можете использовать это поле для передачи ИД книги с фронта, но при записи в БД нужно все равно создавать объект Book и ложить его в поле book у класса `Chapter`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! То что нужно!:)

Answer (score -2):

**Вопрос #1:** Попробуйте использовать аннотацию **@JsonIgnore** из библиотеки **Jackson**

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Спасибо, @JsonIgnore тоже оказался не лишним, при получении объекта с книгой методом GET /book/{id}.